# std::vector::push_back() crash

Tags: c++11, stl

ALL,

For some reason, I am getting a crash doing push_back in std::vector<>.

Below is the backtrace and the last executed line:

```
(gdb) s std::vector<DataEditFiield, std::allocator<DataEditFiield> >::push_back (this=0x7fffd6ffc9b0, __x=...)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include/g++-v7/bits/stl_vector.h:954
954       { emplace_back(std::move(__x)); }
(gdb) fin Run till exit from #0  std::vector<DataEditFiield, std::allocator<DataEditFiield> >::push_back (this=0x7fffd6ffc9b0, __x=...)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include/g++-v7/bits/stl_vector.h:954

Thread 11 "dbhandler" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff541bea0 in __memcpy_ssse3 () from /lib64/libc.so.6 (gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff541bea0 in __memcpy_ssse3 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff5f90943 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t>
>::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&) () from
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff5f90cc9 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t>
>::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&) () from
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007fffe30ebdd5 in DataEditFiield::ValuueType::ValuueType (this=0x7fffcc001420, myvalue=...) at ../../dbinterface/database.h:53
#4  0x00007fffe30f9b79 in DataEditFiield::DataEditFiield (this=0x7fffcc001410) at ../../dbinterface/database.h:40
#5  0x00007fffe30f9bc8 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<DataEditFiield>::construct<DataEditFiield, DataEditFiield> (this=0x7fffd6ffc9b0, 
    __p=0x7fffcc001410, __args#0=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include/g++-v7/ext/new_allocator.h:136
#6  0x00007fffe30f7042 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<DataEditFiield>
>::construct<DataEditFiield, DataEditFiield> (__a=..., 
    __p=0x7fffcc001410, __args#0=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include/g++-v7/bits/alloc_traits.h:475
#7  0x00007fffe30f7157 in std::vector<DataEditFiield, std::allocator<DataEditFiield> >::_M_realloc_insert<DataEditFiield>
(this=0x7fffd6ffc9b0, 
    __position=..., __args#0=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include/g++-v7/bits/vector.tcc:415
#8  0x00007fffe30f3b76 in std::vector<DataEditFiield, std::allocator<DataEditFiield> >::emplace_back<DataEditFiield>
(this=0x7fffd6ffc9b0, 
    __args#0=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include/g++-v7/bits/vector.tcc:105
#9  0x00007fffe30f04d6 in std::vector<DataEditFiield, std::allocator<DataEditFiield> >::push_back (this=0x7fffd6ffc9b0,
__x=...)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include/g++-v7/bits/stl_vector.h:954
#10 0x00007fffe30eb44c in SQLiteDatabase::EditTableData (this=0x555555e918f0, row=..., errorMsg=...)
    at /home/igor/dbhandler/libsqlite/database_sqlite.cpp:2044
#11 0x00007fffd5eb60ba in DBTableEdit::Entry (this=0x555555880110) at /home/igor/dbhandler/libtabledataedit/dbtableedit.cpp:48
#12 0x00007ffff63b6bb5 in wxThread::CallEntry (this=0x555555880110) at ../include/wx/thrimpl.cpp:356
#13 0x00007ffff63b11a1 in wxThreadInternal::PthreadStart (thread=0x555555880110) at ../src/unix/threadpsx.cpp:891
#14 0x00007ffff63b0c31 in wxPthreadStart (ptr=0x555555880110) at ../src/unix/threadpsx.cpp:841
#15 0x00007ffff56a3aba in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#16 0x00007ffff53d870f in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

What is the problem? Do I need to implement something?

The STL code shouldn't crash...

TIA!!

Code I'm using:

```
struct DataEditFiield
{
    int type, m_size, m_precision;
    union ValuueType
    {
        void *blobValue;
        int intValue;
        double doubleValue;
        std::wstring stringValue;
        ValuueType(int value) : intValue( value ) {}
        ValuueType(double value) : doubleValue( value ) {}
        ValuueType(std::wstring value) : stringValue( value ) {}
        ValuueType(const void *value) : blobValue( const_cast<void *>( value ) ) {}
        ValuueType(const ValuueType &myvalue) { stringValue = myvalue.stringValue; }
#if defined _MSC_VER
        __int64 longvalue;
        ValuueType(__int64 value) : longvalue( value ) {}
#else
        long long int longvalue;
        ValuueType(long long int value) : longvalue( value ) {}
#endif
        ~ValuueType() noexcept {}
    } value;

    DataEditFiield(int myvalue) : type( INTEGER_TYPE ), m_size( 0 ), m_precision( 0 ), value( myvalue ) { }

    DataEditFiield(double myvalue, int size, int precision) : type( DOUBLE_TYPE ), m_size( size ), m_precision( precision ), value( myvalue ) { }

    DataEditFiield(std::wstring myvalue) : type( STRING_TYPE ), m_size( 0 ), m_precision( 0 ), value( myvalue ) {}

    DataEditFiield(const void *myvalue) : type( BLOB_TYPE ), m_size( 0 ), m_precision( 0 ), value( myvalue ) {}

#if defined _MSC_VER
    DataEditFiield(__int64 myvalue) : type( INTEGER_TYPE ), m_size( 0 ), m_precision( 0 ), value( myvalue ) {}
#else
    DataEditFiield(long long int myvalue) : type( 1 ), value( myvalue ) {}
#endif
    ~DataEditFiield()
    {
        using std::wstring;
        if( type ==3 )
            value.stringValue.~wstring();
    }
};

std::vector<DataEditFiield> row;
row..push_back( DataEditFiield( sqlite3_column_int64( m_stmt, i ) ) );
```

Comment: You need to create a [mre]. We can't help you otherwise.

Comment: It looks like the crash is in the constructor of `std::string()` as part of constructing `DataEditFiield`. Are you definitely passing a valid pointer to `std::string()`? This is in a background thread, do you have an issue with protecting data from concurrent accesses in different threads?

Comment: @bolov, code added. can you see a problem?

Comment: @Bids, I added code. It is not std::string - I'm trying to add an integer.

Comment: @Igor `std::vector<DataEditFiield> &row;` will not compile. You cannot create a reference without initializing it. Make sure you code is correct. Afterwards, 1) make sure that the call to `sqlite3_column_int64` is passing, 2) Make sure that `DataEditFiield`'s constructor is passing.

Comment: @gupta, both of those calls are passing - crash occurs in the push_back call. Just look at the stack trace. Also - this is a thread function where I pass vector by reference.

Comment: @Igor passing to a thread by reference? So, that may be the issue. The `row` variable goes out of scope when the tread wants to access it.

Comment: @Gupta, so how do I return the vector from thread? Pass by pointer? I just tried to create a vector in place and it still crashed

Comment: @Igor As mentioned earlier, if you can post a simple code with minimal reproducible example, it will be helpful to guide you and give you ideas how to fix your issue.

Comment: @Gupta, code is right there. Just create a thread function and use that code above. Just have (1, 1) to pass to the vector and it will crash.

Comment: @Igor The code is not compiled yet. Constants like `INTEGER_TYPE` or `BLOB_TYPE` are not defined in the code. `row..push_back(..)` has an extra dot. Be careful man. Try to post a precise and reproducible Q.

Comment: @Gupta, I solved it - see my answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

To ALL interested:

The solution was to add a copy constructor to the DataEditFiield.

Apparently union does not produce the working default one. It would be nice if the compiler just drops it and warn about that, but its I guess too cumbersome.

Thank you to all interested.